# Pick the object with the closest date and source

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following object, where i need to pick the values of the object with the closest date and time

For example

```
Result:[
  {
     event:[
        {
          time:2016-01-21T00:12:03Z
          source: xyz
        }
     ]
  },

   {
     event:[
        {
          time:2016-01-20T00:06:12Z,
          source: xyz
        }
     ]

   },

   {
     event:[
        {
          time:2016-01-20T00:06:12Z,
          source: abc
        }
     ]

   }

]
```

So from the above json, i want to only pick the **Result** obj with the latest time and source value of xyz

Comment: This object has invalid syntax.

Comment: thanks @torazaburo i corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you sort the list, then the latest time is simply the last item in the list:

```
Result = Result.filter(function(item) {
  return item.event[0].source === 'xyz';
});

Result = Result.sort(function(a, b) {
  var aAsDate = new Date(a.event[0].time);
  var bAsDate = new Date(b.event[0].time);

  return aAsDate - bAsDate;
});

console.log(Result[Result.length - 1]);
```

Comment: yes but i need to only pick values that have source:xyz

Comment: thanks, but the sort still returns back both the objects instead of the one with the latest time

Comment: yes - that's why I put a `console.log(Result[Result.length - 1])`. The element at `Result[Result.length - 1]` after the sort is the latest time element.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, take all `xyz` and `abc` into separate arrays.

```
//for demo, i only filter all xyz
var xyz_result = result.filter(function(item) { 
    return item.event.filter(function(event){ 
        return event.source === 'xyz' 
    }).length > 0; 
});
```

Then sort them with date

```
xyz_result.sort(function(a, b){ 
    var aDate = new Date(a.event[0].time);
    var bDate = new Date(b.event[0].time);

    //this might be tricky, i hope it has only 1 event

    if(aDate > bDate) { 
        return -1; //you can play around with this values
    } else if(aDate < bDate)) { 
        return 1; 
    } else { 
        return 0; 
    } 
});
```

Now `xyz_result` is sorted by *time* property, and `xyz_result[0]` has latest event

Comment: i tried the sort but still both the objects get picked up

Comment: yes, both objects are picked into array, but array[0] has latest value. Read carefuly

Answer (score 0):

First of all, consider the first event is the latest event in the Result json like this.

```
var latest = Result[0];
```

Now iterate the Result json through the javascript **forEach** function and compare event time with considered latest event variable like this.

**Example-**

```
Result.forEach(function(ele){
  if(latest != ele) {
    var t = new Date(latest.event[0].time);
    var t1 = new Date(ele.event[0].time);
    if(t < t1)
      latest = ele;
  }
});
```

You can see that latest variable has the latest event.

```
console.log(latest.event[0].time);
console.log(latest.event[0].source);
```

Comment: @RajPowar now I've updated the answer with javascript. There is no any jquery is used.